# Parse Cloudformation string response from AWS SDK in Python

Tags: python, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, boto3

The AWS SDK in Python has a function `get_template` to get a Cloudformation template.

The fact is the `TemplateBody` is a return as string and even without `"`. This makes the parsing pretty hard.

Do you have any suggestions on how to properly parse it and manipulate the data as `dict` in Python3.x?

I've tried with `yaml.load`, `json.loads` but w/o any luck.

on [Github](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1468) theere is an issue about this but no one seems to take care of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ruamel.yaml` package. This is my test code,

```
import boto3
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='<region>')
client = session.client('cloudformation')

response = client.get_template(StackName='<stackname>')

yaml = YAML()
result = yaml.load(response['TemplateBody'])

yaml.dump(result, sys.stdout)
```

and the result is

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: >
  AWS CloudFormation template to create a new VPC
  or use an existing VPC for ECS deployment
  in Create Cluster Wizard. Requires exactly 1
  Instance Types for a Spot Request.
Parameters:
  EcsClusterName:
    Type: String
    Description: >
      Specifies the ECS Cluster Name with which the resources would be
      associated
    Default: default
  EcsAmiId:
    Type: String
    Description: Specifies the AMI ID for your container instances.
  EcsInstanceType:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: >
      Specifies the EC2 instance type for your container instances.
      Defaults to m4.large
    Default: m4.large
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid EC2 instance type.
...
```

The `result` in my code is not string and even not dict type but it is a dict-like object of ruamel.yaml package. You can parse the element from the `result` such as

```
result['AWSTemplateFormatVersion']
```

where it gives

```
2010-09-09
```

Comment: I've tried it but it did not work i get a str because the CF template is an YAML so when it is an YAML returns a string.

Comment: Str for what? My `result`? or `response['TemplateBody']`? The `response['TemplateBody']` is returned as string by definition of boto3..

Comment: I modified my answer a bit and hope to be helpful to you.

Comment: I tried your exact approach and now it works. the funny thing is that when I dump the respnse and then I load the file i don't get a `dict`-like but a `str`. wondering what can go wrong in the dump process